# С++. Явная специализация

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Есть шаблон для обобщенного типа данных:

```
template <typename T>
void Swap(T &, T &);
```

Специализация используется, если для какого-то конкретного типа данных (скажем int) нужно использовать иную реализацию функции.

```
template <>
void Swap<int>(int &, int &);
```

Но того же можно добиться определив обычную функцию

```
void Swap(int &, int &);
```

Зачем тогда нужны явные специализации.
Приведите пожалуйста пример невозможности использования обычной функции и
необходимости использования, преимущества явной специализации.

Comment: Рекурсивные шаблоны. Да и вообще, частичная специализация - когда не все параметры шаблона участвуют в специализации.

Comment: Добавлю, что шаблонными могут быть не только функции, но и классы, например.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вопрос, как видно, именно о шаблонах функций. У шаблонов функций не бывает частичной специализации.

Answer (score 11):

Для шаблонов функций *явная специализация* шаблона и обычная *перегрузка* нешаблонной функцией - это два альтернативных способа задания частной версии функции, как вы сами заметили.

Обычно рекомендуется для этой цели пользоваться именно вторым вариантом - перегрузкой, а явную специализацию не трогать. Явная специализация предназначена в первую очередь для шаблонов классов, а не функций. Именно на эту тему есть статья Herb Sutter: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Суть тут в том, что *перегруженные* функции, как шаблонные так и нешаблонные, непосредственно видны процессу overload resolution, а вот *явные специализации* шаблонов в процессе overload resolution не участвуют вообще. В overload resolution участвуют только главные (базовые) шаблоны, а их явные специализации изначально тихонько стоят в сторонке. Они будут рассматриваться только позже, и только те, чей главный (базовый) шаблон "победит" в процессе overload resolution.

К сожалению, соответствие между базовыми шаблонами и явными специализациями может зависеть от порядка их объявления, что может вести к неприятным и неожиданным эффектам.

В частности приводится такой пример

```
template <typename T> void foo(T);   // 1: базовый шаблон
template <typename T> void foo(T *); // 2: еще один, перегруженный базовый шаблон
template <> void foo<>(int *);       // 3: явная специализация для базового шаблона 2

int *p; 
foo(p);
```

В этом случае, по вышеупомянутым правилам языка в процессе overload resolution участвуют только базовые шаблоны 1 и 2 (но не специализация 3). Побеждает шаблон 2. Только после этого во внимание принимаются возможные специализации этого шаблона. В результате выбирается явная специализация 3 и вызывается вариант 3.

А теперь просто поменяем местами объявления 2 и 3

```
template <typename T> void foo(T);   // 1: базовый шаблон
template <> void foo<>(int *);       // 3: явная специализация для базового шаблона 1
template <typename T> void foo(T *); // 2: еще один, перегруженный базовый шаблон

int *p; 
foo(p);
```

Теперь, при таком порядке объявления, явная специализация 3 привязывается уже к базовому шаблону 1 (!), а не 2. Далее в процессе overload resolution, как и прежде, участвуют только базовые шаблоны 1 и 2. Побеждает, как и прежде, шаблон 2. Но теперь явная специализация 3 уже не принимается во внимание и не выбирается, ибо она теперь "принадлежит" шаблону 1. В результате вызывается вариант 2.

Как видите, как будто невинная перестановка объявлений серьезно поменяла семантику кода. Чтобы этого не происходило, рекомендуется для шаблонов функций применять механизм перегрузки, а не явной специализации. Это позволит частным версиям функции участвовать в процессе overload resolution сразу и самостоятельно, а не прятаться за широкой спиной своего базового шаблона с туманными перспективами.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ *AnT*'а могу обобщить и дополнить следующим:

Сначала выбирается "лучший" кандидат среди обычных функций и базовых шаблонов, причем предпочтение отдается обычным функциям. Если же более подходящим является базовый шаблон, то проверяется "а нет ли у него еще более подходящих специализаций" и, если таковые существуют (причем чтобы специализация шаблонной функции считалась таковой, базовый шаблон должен быть объявлен в коде перед этой специализацией), то выбирается одна из них.

*Контрольный пример:*

```
template <typename T>
void func(T parm);

template <>
void func<int>(int parm){}

void func(int parm){} // вызовется именно эта функция

void main()
{
    func(0);
}
```

---

Также начиная с *C++11* шаблоны удобно использовать для рекурсивных вычислений причем в связке с обычными функциями. Стало куда удобнее писать функции с переменным числом параметров (в отличие от аналогичного формата с переменным числом параметров, оставшегося со времен *C*).

Правда остались некоторые ограничения, например, тип `Types...` - это "пакет параметров" шаблона, получать параметры из которого можно только последовательно (т.е. например, получить параметр из пакета по его индексу невозможно).

Например, вычисление суммы неопределенного числа аргументов:

```
int calcSum(int parm)
{
    return parm;
}

template<typename... Args>
int calcSum(int parm1, Args... args)
{
    return parm1 + calcSum(args...);
}

void main()
{
    int sum = calcSum(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Или даже так:

```
template<typename... T>
void ignore(T...) {}

template<typename... T>
int calcSum(T... parms)
{
    int result = 0;
    ignore(result += parms...);
    return result;
}

void main()
{
    int sum = calcSum(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Раньше же приходилось не хило так поизвращаться с функциями вида:

```
void calcSum(int* parm, ...)
{
   // передвигаться по параметрам в стиле: ++parm;
   // т.е. крайне желательно, чтобы все параметры имели один тип
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Имитация перегрузки функций по возвращаемому значению

```
template <typename T>
T get_value();

template<>
int get_value()
{
    return 42;
}

template<>
double get_value()
{
    return 3.14;
}
```

Использование

```
auto x = get_value<int>();
auto y = get_value<double>();
```

Однако, если использовать с типом не имеющим специализации, обшибку выдаст лишь линкер, но не компилятор. Но можно определить обобщенную функцию так

```
template <typename T>
T get_value()
{
    static_assert(0, "no specialization for this type provided");
}
```

это позволит получить ошибку во время компиляции.